# Drupal 7 ajax_command_* creates unwanted div

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I'm populating a select box using an AJAX callback in Drupal 7. I've tried both ajax_command_append() and ajax_command_html() to set the new `<option...>` statements, but both these wrap the HTML that I create inside a `<div>`. This causes the `<select>` to not display any of the options.

Is there a way to tell Drupal "Hey stupid, this is exactly the HTML I want, don't mess with it"?

I can code some jQuery to remove the div I guess, but it would be a lot better if I can prevent it from being added in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can!

Declare your own custom js callback. In below example, I used a span instead of the divs. But you can obviously remove the wrapper alltogether.

PHP:

```
function my_ajax_callback() {
  $data = 'saved!';
  // instead of using ajax_command_html, we provide our own 
  // js custom callback function
  $output = array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => array(
      array('command' => 'myjscallback', 'data' => $data),
    ),
  );

  return $output; 
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.myjscallback = function (ajax, response, status) {
    $('#save-btn-message').html('<span>' + response.data + '</span>');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.
Just use this instead:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#mywrapper', 'html', array($output));
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems the answer is "no" (or at least not without hacking core, and I'll have no dead kittens on my conscience).

misc/ajax.js contains the following:

```
var new_content_wrapped = $('<div></div>').html(response.data);
```

The comments therein go on to explain why they require the first HTML element to be a top-level one. If it is, the `<div>` wrapper is not used. In my case, I'm replacing `<option>` elements, so I get the `<div>`.

Now I could just replace the entire `<select>`, but that causes other issues in my case due to scripts that style things at page load. Rather than find those and re-fire them, it looks like it'll be easier to just ajax_command_invoke a script to run after my options are loaded to remove the div wrapper.

EDIT: As a workaround, I found I can do `ajax_command_invoke($selector, 'html', array('<option...>'));` and it bypasses the div addition code. Kinda sneaky, but it works...

Comment: @see my comment in answer to horlyk. Be careful with ajax_command_invoke because Drupal.attachBehaviors will be not called and break any .use-ajax button or other js behaviors to be processed in the new content.

Answer (score 0):

you can use seen on this link http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax

for more reference and example download this module http://drupal.org/project/examples
it has all the examples of custom code and "ajax_example" as well

Comment: I'm quite familiar with that page. It doesn't tell how to eliminate the generated enclosing div.

Answer (score -1):

**It works for me!**

```
    $selector = '#my-select';
    $method = 'append';
    $opts = array('new option');

    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke($selector, $method, $opts);

    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

Comment: Using ajax_command_invoke work well to avoid the extra div, but in this case, Drupal.attachBehaviors() is not called (@see ajax.js insert and invoke method). If the content you add contains a .use-ajax button, It will be not processed and doesn't work...